# Prove sets are equal

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I would like to show that the following two sets are equal $A=\{x^2:0\le x \le1\}$ and $B=\{y \in \mathbb{R}:0 \le y \le 1\}$. The strategy I would like to use is to show if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ then $B=A$.

I am unsure of the intermediate steps I could use to get to $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. What are some different ways I could prove this?

Comment: You start a sentence "Suppose $ y \in B$" and see if you can deduce that It must be in $A$. Then you start with an element of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do one direction;   leave the other for you.

Let $x\in A$.  Then $x=t^2$, where $t\in [0,1]$. But $t\in[0,1]\implies t^2\in[0,1]$*. Then $x\in [0,1]$. So $x\in B$.

*To justify this,  you could note that $f(t)=t^2$ is an increasing function on $[0,1]$, with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to show $A \subseteq B$, you want to show that if a number $z$ meets the conditions for belonging in $A$, then it also meets the conditions for belonging in $B$, and *vice versa*.

So suppose that $z$ is in $A$.  Then $z = x^2$ for some $x$ satisfying $0 \leq x \leq 1$.  You want to show that $z$ is in $B$.  That is, you want to show $z = y$ for some $y$ satisfying $0 \leq y \leq 1$.  Can you figure out how $y$, if it were to exist, must depend on $x$, which we know exists?